# How do I parse DOM with serverless js (Cloudflare Worker)?

Tags: javascript, serverless, cloudflare-workers

I'm building a tool, which core structure is: make an AJAX request to Cloudflare worker, which fetches HTML data, and then returns it.

So the steps are:

1. Send request from client
2. Worker receives request and makes another, which returns a response as a typical HTML document.
3. Aaaand on the third step I have two options:

- to return the obtained HTML back via AJAX response and then parse it on client
- to parse HTML first, and then return processed data via AJAX response

The first one is straightforward: I receive the response from my worker, and insert it the returned HTML somewhere in a hidden `<div>` and then parse it.

The reason I would prefer to go with a second one, though, is not to waste the bandwidth while delivering HTML from Cloudflare Worker back to client, because original page has a lot of irrelevant bloat. I mean, for example, the original page looks something like this:

```html
<div class="very-much-bloat" id="some-other-bloat" useful_parameter ="value">
    <div id="some-other-irrelevant-info" id="really-great-id">
        something that I need
    </div>
</div>
```

And all that I need from this is, for example

```
{
    "really-great-id"  : "something that I need",
    "useful_parameter" : "value"
}
```

If I go with the first step, it would be pretty straightforward to parse it in-browser, however I'll waste bandwidth for delivering a lot of information that is later disposed of.

However, if the second one would involve using complex libraries, it wouldn't be probably a way to go since max execution time per request is 10ms (that's a free plan on Cloudflare, which otherwise is plenty enough: 100,000 requests per day is more than I probably ever need with this app).

The question is: is there any efficient way to parse HTML on Cloudflare worker without breaking 10ms time limit? Page size obtained with worker is around 10-100 KB, parsed data size is around 1-10KB (10 times less than original roughly). While I understand that 100KB may not sound like a lot, it's still mostly garbage that's better to filter as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare Workers currently does not support the DOM API. However, it supports an alternative HTML parsing API that might work for you: `HTMLRewriter`

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/html-rewriter/

This API is different from DOM in that it operates in a streaming fashion: JavaScript callbacks are invoked as the HTML data streams in from the server, without ever holding the entire document in memory at one time. If it fits your use case, it may allow you to respond faster and use fewer resources than a DOM-based solution would. The CPU time used by `HTMLRewriter` itself does not even count against the 10ms limit -- only the time spent by your callbacks counts. So if you design your callbacks carefully, you should have no problem staying within the limit.

Note that `HTMLRewriter` is primarily designed to support modifying an HTML document as it streams through. However, it should not be too hard to have it consume the document and generate a completely different kind of data, like JSON. Essentially, you would set up the rewriter so that the "rewritten" HTML is discarded, and you'd have your callbacks separately populate some other data structure or write to some other stream that represents the final result.